# What is the origin of the one-horned rabbit so common in fantasy and isekai stories?

Tags: tropes

Dozens of fantasy and *isekai* stories have the one-horn-rabbit as a staple beginner's monster.

[image: Horned rabbit in the Re:Monster manga]

Some examples:

1. *Re:Monster* (day 4)
2. *I Said Make My Abilities Average!* (ch. 19)
3. *Kenshi o Mezashite Nyūgaku Shitanoni Mahō Tekisei 9999 Nandesukedo!?* (web novel ch. 22)
4. *Nidoume no Jinsei wo Isekai de* (ch. 23)
5. *Saikyou no Shokugyou wa Yuusha demo Kenja demo naku Kanteishi (Kari) rashii desu yo?* (ch. 2)

What is the origin of this monster, and why is it so common?

Answer (score 6):

It's possibly a reference to **[Bunicorn](https://dragon-quest.org/wiki/Bunicorn), an early-stage recurring enemy in *Dragon Quest* series**.

> [image: bunicorn]
>
> Bunicorns are rabbits with a single horn, parodying the fabled unicorns. They have gray fur, and the horn is often a yellowish brown shade. [...].
>
> As enemies typically encountered at the start of a game, Bunicorns are not particularly strong, though they typically outweigh the likes of Slimes [...].

The creature first appeared on [*Dragon Quest III*](https://dragon-quest.org/wiki/Dragon_Quest_III:_The_Seeds_of_Salvation) in 1988 (Japanese NES release).

Considering that *Dragon Quest* is really popular in Japan, I think this is the most possible reason for using it as a beginner's monster, as an alternative to [Slime](https://dragon-quest.org/wiki/Slime).

Comment: Yes, there are tons of DQ references in the novels. I think you are corrrect.

Answer (score 4):

They're called Al-mi'raj. And they have been around for hundreds of years.
Dragon Quest is only the first game to include them in.

Series could just be using them as a starting monster as a simple DQ reference... But it could also be because they're like one the most easiest fantasy animal to kill. The most they can do is scare off wild animals.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-mi%27raj#cite_note-:0-1

Wiki doesn't go into much detail about them. So here's another website just in case you're curious to know more.

https://abookofcreatures.com/2015/04/15/miraj/